# Unable to assign VMs to azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I was able to create 2 Linux VM's in azurerm_availability_set and now would like to attach these VM's to azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool but other than the options listed below in my code. I don't see an availability set option but when I goto the Azure portal I see an availability set option through the portal. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong here.

Please review the code below and let me know as of where can I add availability set option. So that I can attach the 2 VMs.

```
resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "backend_pool" {
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  loadbalancer_id     = "${azurerm_lb.lb.id}"
  name                = "webBackendPool"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assigning VMs in the load balancer backend pool is actually to assign the network interfaces of VMs to the backend pool, so you could use [azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/network_interface_backend_address_pool_association.html) resource to binds the NICs of VMs to a backend pool.

For example,

```
...
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "test" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-nic"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = "${azurerm_subnet.internal.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id = "${azurerm_public_ip.test.id}"
  }
}
...

 resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "test" {
      network_interface_id    = "${azurerm_network_interface.test.id}"
      ip_configuration_name   = "testconfiguration1"
      backend_address_pool_id = "${azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.backend_pool.id}"
    }

resource "azurerm_lb" "lb" {
  name                = "weblb"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"  
  sku                 = "${var.lb_sku}"

   frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${var.frontend_name}"
    subnet_id                     = "${azurerm_subnet.frontend.id}"
    private_ip_address            = "10.0.1.10"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
  }
}
resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "backend_pool" {
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  loadbalancer_id     = "${azurerm_lb.lb.id}"
  name                = "webBackendPool"
}
```

Comment: I have tried network_interface_id / s and get the following error

1 error(s) occurred:

* azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.backend_pool: : invalid or unknown key: network_interface_id /s

Comment: Could you refer to the example in my reply, or show your code?